# How to fix Vue.js error 405 Not Allowed in production mode used with Nginx + Symfony + Axios?

Tags: symfony, vue.js, nginx, axios

Good morning everyone,

I have an issue and it's been a month now (seriously) I try to fix it. Here it is:
My stack is Symfony Nginx Vue.js.

My project structure :
[image]

The api folder is the API code in PHP/Symfony4.4
The back folder is the admin panel in Vue.JS

Both of them are (git) submodules.

**My concern is on the Vuejs session. To access the app, we need to log in. In dev mode, everything works fine but not in production mode!
Actually, when I submit the form; I have a *405 Not Allowed error***

I have no idea on what is happening. So here are my project confs.

1. **docker-compose.yml**

```
    api:
        container_name: svisor-api
        build:
            context: ./api
        env_file:
            - ./api/.env
        depends_on:
            - db
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./api:/var/www/api:rw
            # - /var/www/html/vendor

    nginx:
        container_name: svisor-nginx
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        depends_on:
            - api
            - website
            - back
        volumes:
            - ./website:/var/www/html:rw
            - ./api:/var/www/api:rw
            - ./nginx.default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "80:80"

    back:
        container_name: svisor-back
        build:
            context: ./back
        restart: always
```

2. **back Dockerfile**

Based on the [official doc](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#docker-nginx), I did this

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
 
RUN echo "================   BUILDING BACK   =================="
RUN apk add npm
 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY package*.json ./ 
COPY ./ . 
RUN npm install 
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage 
RUN mkdir -p /app 
COPY --from=build-stage /app /app COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

1. **back Nginx conf**
   Also based on th vuejs official doc,

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /app/dist;
    index  index.html;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

4. **the vue conf**

```
//file vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
    }
}
```

My env vars are :
[image]

And the login code :

```
    actions: {
        login({commit}, credentials) {

            console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_URL);
            console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL);

            return axios
                .post(process.env.VUE_APP_URL + '/login_check', credentials)
                .then(({data}) => {
                    commit('SET_LOGGED_USER', data)
                })
        },
    }
```

(The console.log confirm me if I'm in dev or prod env).

5. **The global Nginx conf**

```
### API server
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.svisor.localhost;
    root /var/www/api/public;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api.access_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/api.error_log;

   location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass api:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
       internal;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
     return 404;
   }
}

### Back server
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name back.svisor.localhost;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/back.access_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/back.error_log;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://back;
    }

    error_page   400 402 403 404  /40x.html;
    location = /40x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

## Visual error

In dev mode, it is ok
[image]

But in prod mode,
[image]

The error in detail :
[image]
[image]

6. **some API router show**
   We can see the route (/login_check) I've been calling exists and is POST method.
   [image]

### What Have I already done ?

I am pretty sure I have read 80% of google results (from page 1 to 10); I have search in github issues of every project.
And it's always the same thing : CORS (Access-Control-Allow-Origin/Methods). I tried all that but nothing works. I even tried things I don't even remember (from 50x error to craziest ones). Some asking to implement an OPTIONS call but I don't know how.
Looking at how many tickets there are on this topic in Laravel forum, it is obviously a big problem.
Some CORS source I read :
[Mozilla Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://web.dev/cross-origin-resource-sharing/)

Sorry for all the text and I hope I gave enough data so that you can help me fix this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I see, in dev mode all unknown requests are being proxied to `VUE_APP_API_URL` [according to doc](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy). So even if on your screenshot of request in dev mode it is shown as `localhost:8080/login_check`, it will be proxied to your `VUE_APP_API_URL` destination.

Now in prod mode you are making post request to `VUE_APP_URL`. This is just nginx server for your static files, no proxy. As a fix you could update your login code with substituting `VUE_APP_URL` with `VUE_APP_API_URL`.

```
return axios
   .post(process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL + '/login_check', credentials)
   .then(({data}) => {
      commit('SET_LOGGED_USER', data)
   })
```

Dev mode proxy works only for vue dev server. It doesn't work for resulting static files.

Comment: Hello, Yeah it is! It works!

However, I didn't have to use `VUE_APP_API_URL`. When I did that, there were an error in dev mode; seems like it needs to route by **localhost:8080** first before redirecting to the API link. So I kept my confs and/but for prod mode, VUE_APP_API_URL & `VUE_APP_URL` have same values (good? don't know).

Moreover, I had to edit my nginx conf to add the OPTIONS bloc from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/michiel/1064640) seems like the most important is the **return 204**. 

After that, everything worked like a charm.

Thank you.